# How to manage plagues?

Tags: a-dark-room

About every half hour or so, a plague sweeps through the village. It costs 5 medicine to stop, which is crazy expensive. I cannot figure out how to possibly produce enough medicine to keep up with the plagues.

It almost doesn't matter because within two minutes of the plague passing, I'm almost back up to my current max (80).

So is it pointless to devote 100% of your efforts to medicine production?

It really kind of ruins the magic to just let everyone die, but the cost is so small compared to the cost of saving them.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - I don't like this event either. It's not balanced and feels much too powerful. It was not part of the original game. It was added by a volunteer at some point.

I would vote to fix it by sending a pull request changing the number. Personally I'd remove the event entirely, but if the event only cost 1 medicine, that would at least be more balanced.

edit: Looks like the scenes are here:

https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/blob/9e3874bc8ee1dffe7625015ab24b5131588a7251/script/events/outside.js#L94

'Sickness' and 'Plague'.

If you have more than 10 villagers, it takes 1 medicine to cure, or kills up to half your villagers.
If you have more than 50 villagers, it takes 5 medicine to cure, or kills up to 90. ouch. Even if you do pay 5 medicine, it still kills 3-7.

I'd vote to lower the price to 1 in both cases, and/or delete 'Plague' entirely.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't realize they took community edits. After some more play time, it seems like this event only really happens if you sit on the village view. If you leave it in the room or the wilderness, it almost never comes up. I wonder if I could rework it so that they all have the same chance, but lower the cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can get loads of medicine by killing "shivering" strangers. They're quite common a little less than half way out from the village. Abandoned cities have medicine some times, too.